# play framework working with json objects in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Hello i am beginner to scala play framework.I have created a simple registration form and connected to mysql to insert rows.It worked well. Now i want to display those inserted rows on same page without refreshing the page using json . Kindly suggest me an idea how to get the inserted rows on the same page.Thanks in advance.Here is my following code

```
Routes:
# Home page
GET     / controllers.Application.index
GET     /createform                 controllers.StudentController.createform()
POST    /save                   controllers.StudentController.save()
```

Controller : Student controller

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._

import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

import views.html
import models.Student

object StudentController extends Controller {


val studentform= Form (

tuple(
"firstname"->text,
"lastname"->text
    )
)
def createform = Action {

Ok(html.createform(studentform))

}

def save = Action { implicit request=>

studentform.bindFromRequest.fold(
errors=> BadRequest(html.createform(errors)),
{
    case(firstname,lastname)=>Student.create(firstname,lastname)
    Redirect(routes.Application.index())
}

    )

}

}

Application Controller

package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {

    Redirect(routes.StudentController.createform)
    //Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }

}
```

Models:

package models

```
import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current

import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._

case class Student (

    id:Pk[Long]=NotAssigned,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String

)


object Student {

def create(firstname: String,lastname:String) : Unit={

DB.withConnection{ implicit Connection=>

SQL("insert into student (Firstname,Lastname)" + "values({firstname},{lastname})"
).on(
'firstname->firstname,
'lastname->lastname
).executeUpdate()
    }

}
```

}

view
createform.scala.html

```
@(studentform: Form[(String,String)])

@import helper._

@main(title="Student Registration Form"){

@form(action=routes.StudentController.save){

    <fieldset>
<legend>Add Student</legend>

@inputText(
field=studentform("firstname"),
args='_label->"FirstName"
)

@inputText(
field=studentform("lastname"),
args='_label->"LastName"
)
<br/>
<div class="actions">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<a href="@routes.Application.index">Cancel</a>
</div>

    </fieldset>


}

}
```

index.scala.html

```
@main("Welcome to Play 2.0") {

    <a href="/createform">Add a new Student</a>
}
```

kindly suggest me an idea to store the inserted data in a JSON object and same inserted rows on the same page  in scala.Thanks in advance

Comment: As for me your question is not clear, what is your problem, you don't now how to create `json object` from your `student object`? Or how to create `Json response` or how manipulate it on your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use json reads and writes then pass in student as an object to your create method:

```
object Student {

  implicit object PkFormat extends Format[Pk[Long]] {
    def reads(json: JsValue):JsResult[Pk[Long]] = JsSuccess(Id(json.as[Long]))
    def writes(id: Pk[Long]):JsNumber = JsNumber(id.get)
  }

  implicit val studentReads: Reads[Student] = (
    (__ \ "id").readNullable[Pk[Long]].map(_.getOrElse(NotAssigned)) ~
    (__ \ "firstname").read[String] ~
    (__ \ "lastname").read[String]
  )(Student.apply _)

  implicit val studentWrites = Json.writes[Student]

  def create(student: Student): Student = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>

      val id: Long = student.id.getOrElse {
        SQL("select next value for student_id_seq").as(scalar[Long].single)
      }

      SQL(
        """
          insert into student values (
            {id}, {firstname}, {lastname}
          )
        """
      ).on(
        'id -> id,
        'firstname -> student.firstname
        'lastname -> student.lastname
      ).executeUpdate()

      student.copy(id = Id(id))
    }
  }

}
```

Then "same page" can just be an ajax submitted form passing student object with firstname and lastname to the create method, then re-rendering or appending to the list of students. You can pass the response back by returning the newly added student, then appending the result, or calling the db again for the entire list of students and render the entire list.