# Render json data to the view with play! scala 2.2.3

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

Here is a beginner question :

I have defined `Event` like this :

```
case class Event(id: Pk[Long], name: String, userId: Pk[Long])

object Event {
  private val EventParser: RowParser[Event] = {
    get[Pk[Long]]("id") ~
    get[String]("name") ~
    get[Pk[Long]]("userId") map {
      case id ~ name ~ userId => Event(id, name, userId)
    }
  }

  def findAll(): Seq[Event] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("select * from events").as(EventParser *)
    }
  }
}
```

And I render it to the view like this :

```
  def events = Action {
    val events: Seq[Event] = Event.findAll()

    Ok(views.html.events(events))
  }
```

But I would like to return Json data.

`Json.toJson(events)` can't be used since events type is `Seq`.
I didn't find a good tutorial on the subject and I tried to follow this answer : [play framework working with json objects in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869968/play-framework-working-with-json-objects-in-scala) but it doesn't seem to work with play 2.2.

So my question is : Do you know an easy way to render a sequence in Json to the view after accessing database?

Comment: Have you defined `Writes` for `Event` ?

Comment: I tried but without success since the answers I found don't work with play! 2.2.3, do you have any link? (I'm very new to Play!)

Comment: What do you mean they don't work? Not much has changed in the json api in the past year or so: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators

Comment: I'm sorry, I just begin with Play! and I have already read that but without success for a type sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

object Event {

  ...

  implicit def pkWrites[T : Writes]: Writes[Pk[T]] = Writes {
    case anorm.Id(t) => implicitly[Writes[T]].writes(t)
    case anorm.NotAssigned => JsNull
  }
  implicit val eventWrites = Json.writes[Event]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response but can you please explain me how to render it to the view? (Sorry I'm very new to play and it's a bit difficult to me...)

Comment: Just use Json.toJson(events).  Scala will find the implicit writes to convert Event to JSON (and will use that to build a Seq[Event] writes).